# Prometheus query to calculate avg_over_time up-time, but want to ignore down-time less than 1 minute

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I am new to Prometheus and made a query below trying to display the average up-time of a certain website in percentage for SLA monitoring (let's say Google for example).

```
(avg_over_time(probe_success{instance="https://www.google.com/"}[$__range])) * 100
```

However, is it possible to make the calculate ignore any down-time where it is less than 1 minute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to go about SLAs for probes is using quantile function like:

```
quantile_over_time(0.99, probe_success{instance="https://www.google.com/"}[$__range])
```

It is not exactly this query, but one needs to think from the basic with quantiles in mind.

---

That said, to answer the question directly, avoiding 1-min downtimes, this can help:

```
avg_over_time(((avg_over_time(probe_success{instance="https://www.google.com"}[75s]) * 75) > bool(60))[$__range:]) * 100
```

Lets dissect this query now:

`avg_over_time(probe_success{instance="https://www.google.com"}[75s])` gets average of the probe over 75s, so we can try and ignore 1m downtimes. Call this `UP_TIME_PERCENTAGE`.

`UP_TIME_PERCENTAGE * 75` provides the up time in seconds over the past 75s. Call this `UP_TIME_75S`.

`UP_TIME_75S > bool(60)` provides a boolean 1 or 0 timeline, indicating whether the uptime was more than a minute. Call this `IS_UP_MORE_THAN_1M`

`avg_over_time(IS_UP_MORE_THAN_1M[$__range:]) * 100` results in the percentage of probes with up time more than 1m in the given `$__range`. Note the `:`. It is important to apply `..._over_time` method on sub-queries.